# Spring MVC Annotation config seems not working in sts embedded tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am a newbie to spring mvc and general web app development.

I've created a very simple maven web project with annotated spring mvc configuration, it works fine in standalone tomcat7, but in STS embedded tomcat7, seems the dispatcher servelet is not started at all...

My web configuration class:

```
package com.ma2oo.server.webconfig;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

 import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

 import com.ma2oo.server.config.CoreConfig;
 import com.ma2oo.server.config.RepoConfig;

public class WebInit extends
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { RepoConfig.class, CoreConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { RestConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    String[] ret = new String[1];
    ret[0] = "/";
    return ret;
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
}
}
```

My controller:

```
package com.ma2oo.server.webconfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ma2oo.server.rest.controller"})

public class RestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
}
```

In my server.xml, I've added

```
      <Context docBase="test" path="" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:test"/></Host>
```

But after I started the embedded server, I can browse static content fine, but when I tried to access 127.0.0.1:8080/user/abc/roles, I got 404 error. Also my log4j configuration seems not loaded.

The startup log of tomcat from console, I don't how to access the other logs since it's embedded...

> 

```
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:33 Morning org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Info: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Users\botao\Dropbox\ma2oo\sw\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Quarantine\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Imaging\;.
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:33 Morning org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
Warning: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:test' did not find a matching property.
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
Info: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
Info: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Info: Initialization processed in 850 ms
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Info: Starting service Catalina
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Info: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
Info: validateJarFile(C:\Users\botao\Dropbox\ma2oo\workspace\t1-plain\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\test\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-web-api-7.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
Info: validateJarFile(C:\Users\botao\Dropbox\ma2oo\workspace\t1-plain\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\test\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Info: Deploying web application directory test
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
Info: validateJarFile(C:\Users\botao\Dropbox\ma2oo\workspace\t1-plain\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\webapps\test\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-web-api-7.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:34 Morning org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
Info: validateJarFile(C:\Users\botao\Dropbox\ma2oo\workspace\t1-plain\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\webapps\test\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:35 Morning org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
Info: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:35 Morning org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
Info: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 16, 2014 9:02:35 Morning org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Info: Server startup in 1002 ms
```

Added my pom.xml

> 

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ma2oo</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>internal Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
         <groupId>net.sourceforge.jwebunit</groupId> 
         <artifactId> jwebunit-core </artifactId> 
         <version> 3.1 </version> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

**Work around solution:**

I re-installed tomcat by downloading a .zip from apache web site, and in STS, specify to use this tomcat as default embedded server. Then everything works.

Thanks for the kind help, at least I can proceed with my work now.

Comment: post your pom.xml as well

Comment: Added pom.xml @dhamibirendra

Comment: what option have you selected while creating your local server within STS ? Use workspace metadata / Use Tomcat installation / Use custom location ? Which one of the above 3 ?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to access 127.0.0.1:8080/user/abc/roles ?! i mean isnt your application context root as /test ?

Comment: I am using metadata, so the app is deployed at C:\{project root}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp*

Comment: And I've changed the docBase so that I don't need to add /test, I can access static content without adding /test, so I guess this part is OK.

Comment: @dhamibirendra ,actually I've also tried http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/user/abc/roles, still not working

Comment: quick try: Put below dependency in your pom.xml 
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: Thanks, I've resolved this by trying another tomcat installation. I've updated the question body. Most likely the problem is somehow related to the way STS downloads and installs tomcat server.